# Save a directory from a jar file to the user's disk

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I need to save a directory of resource files from the currently running JAR file to a temporary directory on the user's disk.

Currently, I'm saving files one by one. But now I have a large folder of native libraries to save that I would rather not save this way.

I tried my current code, just in case it treated the directory as a file and saved it anyway.

```
public void saveResource(String name, File outFile) {
    try (InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            name);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);) {

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But sadly, it didn't work. So what's the best way to save a directory of resources to disk?

Comment: *"I have a large folder of native libraries"* Is this a desktop app.?  For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS makes deployment of natives, simple.

Comment: Yes, this is a desktop app. And I have a particular requirement to ship a single JAR file to the user (primarily because the target machines have no Internet connectivity)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the files in that folder and save the files one by one. I guess this is what you are doing now. You can't copy the folder entirely.

or you can use commons-io FileUtils

Comment: Is there a way to check if the name given is a directory? If so, is it possible to make a recursive `saveResources()` that saves every file inside the directory?

Comment: yes File.isDirectory() method tells you that and this should help you in creating recursive method.

Comment: This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/) should help you.

Comment: Ah, but I don't have a `File`: I have either a `URL` if I do `getResource`, or an `InputStream` if I do `getResourceAsStream`.